# How to sort an Access DB Table to show in right order when opening via VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I already have a VBA script that edits this, that, and the other and even opens the table at the end of the script.  The only problem is that I want the data I am viewing to be sorted by columnA, and then by columnB.

How do I do that via VBA in Access 2010?

Comment: The best way to sort it would be in the SQL statement you used to get the data (`ORDER BY columnA, columnB`).  Can you show the portion of the VBA that opens the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see the record set then you could do something like the following:

```
Dim qdef As Dao.QueryDef
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("MyQuery", "SELECT * " & _
                                               "FROM TableName " & _
                                               "ORDER BY columnA, columnB")
DoCmd.OpenQuery "MyQuery"
```

Then once you are done doing whatever it is you want to do with it you could execute the following  to remove the query:

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "MyQuery"
```

Or you could do the following:

```
Dim RSData as DAO.Recordset
Set RSData = CurrentDB.OpenRecordSet("SELECT * " & _
                                     "FROM TableName " & _
                                     "ORDER BY columnA, columnB")
If (RSData.RecordCount > 0) Then
  RSData.MoveFirst
  Do While RSData.EOF <> True
    'HERE YOU CAN WORK WITH EACH FIELD OF THE RECORD INDIVIDUALLY USING 
    RSData.Fields("columnA").value

    RSData.MoveNext
  Loop
End If
```

Then once you are done doing whatever it is you want to do with it you could execute the following:

```
RSData.Close
Set RSData = Nothing
```